# Does every user of a website share the same variable or are they unique to each (even though they're named the same)

Tags: php, ajax, database

say, for example, I have this page solely composed of ajax-queries that every ajax request links to(btw is that smart? or should each ajax request have its own file?). so this page is just filled with if statements that check if a certain ajax request was _POSTed.but inside each of those if statements, I have the same recurring variables for like($Qry, $QryRun, $id.. etc  basically I recycle those variables inside each if statement).. so what I am concerned about is, will there be a problem if say 100 users access that ajax page simultaneously? will the variables get mixed up? will the $Qry variable of the first if statement be reset to the $Qry variable inside the 4th if statement? will it just fail if everyone is inside the same if statement? will the page process each user request 1 at a time? what will happen?

hopefully, you're not too confused lol I am very bad at expressing myself.. thank you for taking the time to read and thanks in advance for your wisdom

Comment: Its good to reuse vars, but no.. every instance of the script is allocated its own place on the stack, so vars are not shared.

Comment: I think it will help to try and ask one question at a time, instead of nesting questions within another.  This makes it easier to read and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your main question, each request will run in it's own encapsulated session.  The variables set in one session will have no bearing on any other sessions.

To answer your secondary question, yes this is probably bad code design.  Without seeing exactly what you're doing, it's likely you should have different endpoints for your ajax requests vs using one big controller with if statements to figure out which request you're receiving.  If some requests are closely related (ie: creating / updating / deleting the same object) then you could group them into one controller.

Comment: CLARIFICATION: basically, every ajax request is a post method that leads to same page i call (ajax-nexus.php). and all those requests basically make changes or/and get information from different tables in my database. the whole page looks like this: if(isset(something)){ do this and return this} over and over again, but using the same variables

Comment: For a very small project that isn't expected to change or be around long or be modified, this may be fine.  Otherwise, you've tied your database, business logic and front end all together in one file.  Check out the SOLID principles of code design.  There are a number of reasons this is bad, "clean architecture" is a great book to read to learn why.  If all your ajax requests hit one file it should be a routing file that is only responsible for forwarding the request to the right controller/action, you'd ideally have model classes that represent your db tables and abstract out the db access.